# Linkto cast issue in spring HATEOAS

Tags: spring, rest, link-to, hateoas

When I try to form the link like below.

```
Link userLink = linkTo((controllerClass).slash("?location="+location+"&scheduledDepartur="+scheduleDepatur).withRel(USER_REL));
```

and it shows error as

```
The method slash(String) is undefined for the type Class<TrainController>
```

When try to use below link method I got

```
Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(controllerClass).getOffTrains(trainStatus, valid, locale).slash("?depatureLocation="+depatureLocation+"&scheduledDepartureDate="+scheduleDepatureDate).withSelfRel());
```

got below error

```
The method slash(String) is undefined for the type HttpEntity<TrainStatus>.
```

Help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

all your parenthesis are off.

```
Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(controllerClass).getOffTrains(trainStatus, valid, locale).slash("?depatureLocation="+depatureLocation+"&scheduledDepartureDate="+scheduleDepatureDate).withSelfRel());
```

should be

```
Link selfLink = linkTo(methodOn(controllerClass).getOffTrains(trainStatus, valid, locale)).slash("?depatureLocation="+depatureLocation+"&scheduledDepartureDate="+scheduleDepatureDate).withSelfRel());
```

I'm surprised those query string parameters you have aren't methods on the getOffTrains controller method..then it would just work for you.